# Error: PK mode for table 'person' is RECORD_KEY, but record key schema is missing

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, database-replication

**Source** : Oracle Database

**Target** : Postgres

**Replication of data using Kafka.**

When I do an insert, it works fine.
When I update a record on the source, it puts a new entry on the target instead of updating the already existing information.
When I delete a record in the table on the source (oracle), I don't see the record getting deleted on the target

**Issue : Insert works fine, but update and delete are not working. Please let me know what should I do to fix the issue ? What am I missing here?**

**Source connector:**

```
{
    "name": "source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.91.139:1521/orcl1",
        "connection.user": "sys as sysdba",
        "connection.password": "oracle",
        "topic.prefix": "person",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "poll.interval.ms": "1000",
        "incrementing.column.name":"ID",
        "query": "SELECT * from person",
        "numeric.mapping":"none",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "validate.non.null": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
       "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
       "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
       "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
       "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"

    }
}
```

**Sink connector:**

```
  {
    "name": "jdbc-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics":"person",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.91.229:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres ",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
       "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
       "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
       "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
       "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
       "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple things I can think of, would justify the delete/update behavior.

you shouldn't have the `transforms`, no need for it.
for the `key.converter` it should be `StringConverter` instead of `AvroConverter`, also you need to define the pk field by setting `pk.fields`

Eventually your sink connector could be something similar to:

```
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics":"person",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.91.229:5432/postgres?user=postgres&password=postgres ",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "pk.fields": "ID",
        "delete.enabled": "true",
  "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081"
```

Please check this to the point [article](https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/#_deleting_records_in_the_target_database_with_kafka_connect_jdbc_sink_connector) by rmoffat